# select ... where not exists

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, select, not-exists

I'm trying to make a custom query to pick up posts (they're really products) from wordpress, where **don't have a meta_query named 'custom_code'**.
I'm trying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM
    wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'product'
AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'draft' )
AND pm.meta_key = 'custom_code' AND pm.meta_key IS NULL
```

I tried with NOT EXISTS, but sql returns error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM
    wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'product'
AND ( p.post_status = 'publish' OR p.post_status = 'draft' )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    select * from wp_postmeta as pm2
    where pm2.meta_key = 'custom_code'
)
```

NOTE: I need to get such posts with status 'publish' as posts with status 'draft'.

**ERROR returned**:

Keyword unrecognized. (Near "NOT", at position 193)

Keyword unrecognized. (Near "EXISTS", at position 197)

Symbol (token) unexpected. (Near "(" at position 204)

**CURRENT POINT**

I did with WordPress API, and it works, but I need to add a LEFT JOIN to also get products with name like the name of each product returned by sentence below. This is the sentence:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page'   => -1,
   'post_type'      =>'product',
   'post_status'      => 'publish,draft',
   'meta_query' => array(
               array(
                 'key' => 'custom_code',
                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
              )),
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND. Change the final AND to WHERE.

Comment: Well meta_key can't be both 'custom_code'  *AND* NULL.  You should add the error message you observe.

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez I think it would be more readable if you translate the error message. I am (for example) not able to understand spanish/portuguese/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page'   => -1,
   'post_type'      =>'product',
   'post_status'      => 'publish,draft',
   'meta_query' => array(
               array(
                 'key' => 'custom_code',
                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
              )),
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

var_dump( $posts_array );
```

**NOTE**

Use this code to print query

```
global $wpdb;
var_dump( $wpdb->last_query);
```

Comment: yes, I did, and it works fine, but I'd need in sql code, to add a left join, to also get products with name like name of each product returned wihich doesn't have custom_code

Answer (score 1):

This is how a query with `NOT EXITSTS` could be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM wp_posts AS p
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND 
      p.post_status ΙΝ ('publish', 'draft' ) AND 
      NOT EXISTS (select * 
                  from wp_postmeta as pm
                  where p.ID = pm.post_id AND 
                        pm.meta_key = 'custom_code')
```

or, using `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm 
   ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'custom_code'
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND 
      p.post_status ΙΝ ('publish', 'draft' ) AND 
      pm.post_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried your NOT EXITSTS sentence, but sql returns me the error I added in my post.

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez The query is syntactically correct as far as I can see.